# NMap Result -A reference meaning

Tags: windows, networking, nmap, internet-security, web-application

I ran nmap command for ssl enum cipher and got the output something like this

(Could not copy paste due to intra network restrictions )

> TLS1.0 TLS----SHA256 -A
>
> ---
>
> --- Cipher Prefernce -Server 
>   Least Strength -A

what does A refer here.Is it like Weak cipher still exists?

Could you Please confirm.I checked nmap help pages but still not clear about this -A reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this Nmap documentation](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html):

> Each ciphersuite is shown with a letter grade (A through F) indicating the strength of the connection. The grade is based on the cryptographic strength of the key exchange and of the stream cipher. The message integrity (hash) algorithm choice is not a factor. The output line beginning with Least strength shows the strength of the weakest cipher offered. The scoring is based on the Qualys SSL Labs SSL Server Rating Guide, but does not take protocol support (TLS version) into account, which makes up 30% of the SSL Labs rating.

So in your output, the weakest cipher offered has a letter grade of `A`.